# Android Facebook SDK 4.0 not returning email

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-sdk-4.0

I'm using the new Facebook SDK and making the following request:

```
GraphRequest request  = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(mLoginResult.getAccessToken(),
                        new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback(){
                            @Override
                            public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {
                                Profile userProfile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();
                                FacebookUser user = new FacebookUser(userProfile, object.optString("email"));
                                sendUserInfo(user);
                            }
                        });
                Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
                parameters.putString("fields", "email");
                request.setParameters(parameters);
                request.executeAsync();
```

The email is not being returned, here is my `LoginManager`'s callback:

```
LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(mFacebookCallbackManager,
            new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                    mLoginResult = loginResult;
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancel() {
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
                }

            });
```

What am I doing wrong? If I remove the request parameters, everything but the email is returned.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, somehow my email wasn't being returned even in Graph Explorer. So I had to add an alternative email, make it my default and everything worked perfectly!